# Get all text in layer by script in CS6

Tags: cs6, photoshop-scripting, script

I'm using photoshop to support my job so I want to know how to get all text in layer and save it into a text file?
I was using this script I found in github to get coordinates and layer:

```
// Enables double-click launching from the Mac Finder or Windows Explorer
#target photoshop

// Bring application forward
app.bringToFront();

// Set active Document variable and decode name for output
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
var docName = decodeURI(activeDocument.name);

// Define pixels as unit of measurement
var defaultRulerUnits = preferences.rulerUnits;
preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

// Define variable for the number of layers in the active document
var layerNum = app.activeDocument.artLayers.length;

// Define variable for the active layer in the active document
var layerRef = app.activeDocument.activeLayer;

// Define varibles for x and y of layers
var x = layerRef.bounds[0].value;
var y = layerRef.bounds[1].value;
var coords = "";

// Loop to iterate through all layers
function recurseLayers(currLayers) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < currLayers.layers.length; i++ ) {
    layerRef = currLayers.layers[i];
    x = layerRef.bounds[0].value;
    y = layerRef.bounds[1].value;
    coords += layerRef.name + "," + x + "," + y + "\n";

    //test if it's a layer set
    if ( isLayerSet(currLayers.layers[i]) ) {
      recurseLayers(currLayers.layers[i]);
    }
  }
}

//a test for a layer set
function isLayerSet(layer) {
  try {
    if ( layer.layers.length > 0 ) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}

// Ask the user for the folder to export to
var FPath = Folder.selectDialog("Save exported coordinates to");

// Detect line feed type
if ( $.os.search(/windows/i) !== -1 ) {
  fileLineFeed = "Windows";
}
else {
  fileLineFeed = "Macintosh";
}

// Export to txt file
function writeFile(info) {
  try {
    var f = new File(FPath + "/" + docName + ".txt");
    f.remove();
    f.open('a');
    f.lineFeed = fileLineFeed;
    f.write(info);
    f.close();
  }
  catch(e){}
}

// Run the functions
recurseLayers(docRef);
preferences.rulerUnits = defaultRulerUnits; // Set preferences back to user 's defaults
writeFile(coords);

// Show results
if ( FPath == null ) {
  alert("Export aborted", "Canceled");
}
else {
  alert("Exported " + layerNum + " layer's coordinates to " + FPath + "/" + docName + ".txt " + "using " + fileLineFeed + " line feeds.", "Success!");
}
```

but with text layer I can't get full text of this layer. Can someone give me some solution?